# Show Featured Image in Your WordPress Admin Dashboard

Tags: wordpress, backend, admin, custom-post-type, dashboard

I want result like.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frY0A.png)

Answer (score 0):

By using WordPress hooks you can display featured Image in column to admin dashboard.
Below filters are used for add column to admin dashboard.

If you want to add column in pages, use below filter.

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-page_columns', 'my_edit_page_columns' ) ;
```

If you want to add column in post, use below filter.

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-post_columns', 'my_edit_page_columns' ) ;
```

If you want to add column in custom post type, replace "Books" with your custom post type slug.

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-books_columns', 'my_edit_page_columns' ) ;
```

Here is a callback function for above action filter.

```
function my_edit_page_columns( $columns ) {
    $new_columns = array(
       'featured_image' => __('featured Image', 'ThemeName'),
   );
return array_merge($columns, $new_columns);
}
```

Now, we need to display featured image in that column, use below respective hook and callback function.

To display featured image in pages, use below action.

```
add_action( 'manage_pages_custom_column' , 'custom_page_column', 10, 2 );
```

To display featured image in post, use below action.

```
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_page_column', 10, 2 );
```

To display featured image in custom post type, replace "Books" with your custom post type slug.

```
  add_action('manage_books_columns' , 'custom_page_column', 10, 2 );
```

Here is a callback function for above action.

```
function custom_page_column($column, $post_id ){
    if ($column == 'featured_image'){
        if (has_post_thumbnail( $post_id ) ){
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ), 'thumbnail' );
            echo '<img src="'.$image[0].'" />';
        }
    }       
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.